# How to Store Leading Zero's in Django

Tags: python, django

I am currently making a view counter for my website, I am going to have it support a count from anywhere between 0 to 9999. I also want to the view count to always display leading zeros, so if there have been 8 views it would be displayed as 0008. I am having the problem where my model is automatically taking away any leading zero's and I cannot figure out how to remove this. If anyone could help me that would be great, also if the number was stored as 0008 would my +1 method in my view still work? Cheers!

View -

```
def listing(request, pk):

    job_listing = JobListing.objects.get(pk=pk)

    def view_counter():
        view_count = job_listing.listing_view_counter
        job_listing.listing_view_counter = view_count + 1
        job_listing.save()

    view_counter()

    context_dict = {'joblistings': job_listing}

    return render(request, 'listing.html', context_dict)
```

Model -

```
class JobListing(models.Model):

    region_choice = (
        ('Auckland', 'Auckland'),
        ('Wellington', 'Wellington'),
        ('Christchurch', 'Christchurch')
    )
    industry_choice = (
        ('Accounting', 'Accounting'),
        ('Agriculture, fishing & forestry', 'Agriculture, fishing & forestry'),
        ('Automotive', 'Automotive'),
        ('Banking, finance & insurance', 'Banking, finance & insurance'),
        ('Construction & Architecture', 'Construction & Architecture'),
        ('Customer service', 'Customer service'),
    )
    employment_type_choice = (
        ('Full Time', 'Full Time'),
        ('Part Time', 'Part Time'),
        ('One-off', 'One-off'),
        ('Other', 'Other')
    )

    user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pay_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    employment_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=employment_type_choice)
    job_description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    business_address_region = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=region_choice)
    business_address_suburb = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    business_industry = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=industry_choice)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null="True")
    telephone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null='True')
    listing_view_counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    active_listing = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Job Listing'

    def clean(self):
        if not (self.email or self.telep

hone):
            raise ValidationError("You must specify either email or telephone")
        if not self.email:
            self.email = "Not Provided"

def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s" % self.job_title
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [stringformat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat) template filter to apply padding to the number inside the template.

For example:

```
{{ job_listing.listing_view_counter|stringformat:"04d" }}
```

Comment: I have used your answer and it seems to be working well, thanks! In saying that for anyone else who has this problem I am not sure if perhaps the answer by Paul Becotte would have been the 'better' way to do it. I just  chose this one because it was easier.

Comment: Using the built in Python string formatting (or zfill) whether using the existing template filter, creating your own, or adding it inside the view is better than trying to manually pad the string yourself as the snippet in Paul's solution describes. The comments to that snippet indicate that as well.

Comment: The Django stringformat link is dead and the edit queue is full. Go [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat).

Answer (score 6):

You're making it too hard on yourself.  Store the data in your code as it is (as a number), and add the 0 padding in your template.

https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/543/

for some code examples to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Not really storing the leading zeros but you can add `property` to your `JobListing` model.

```
@property
def view_counter_display(self):
    return str(self.listing_view_counter).zfill(4)
```

You can then access this in your template as `{{ obj.view_counter_display }}`.

Or just use the builtin [`stringformat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat) filter.

```
{{ obj.listing_view_counter|stringformat:"04d" }}
```

Comment: Apologies! I saw your comment just after I posted mine.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but it still pops up as a top result on search, so here is my solution for saving the "number" with leading zeros in the database.

```
class Sequence(models.Model):
    series_title = models.CharField(max_length = 55)
    series_prefix = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    year = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now().strftime("%Y"))
    sequence = models.CharField(max_length=4, default="0000")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.series  

    def next(series):
        n = Sequence.objects.get(series_title=series)
        n.sequence = str(int(n.sequence) + 1) # convert string to int, add one, return to string

        while len(n.sequence) < 4:        # while not enough leading zeros
            n.sequence = f"0{n.sequence}" # add leading zeros

        return f"{n.series}{n.year}-{n.sequence}"
```